# Ensure Saving of multiple Objects in Django service

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-views, django-admin

So, if the code has some indent problems, it's due to how I pasted it into Stack overflow, but basically I have this service listed below that is ran when a Django webservice is hit. 95% of the time everything works perfectly, but if you look at the amount of .save() is being called, that sometimes the payment object is never saved even though the account.save() is ran. I'm not familiar with calling django commit, but I know due to past projects that it's best practice not to list too many .save()'s in one webservice. Anyone know what I can do to ensure that all the objects are saved or none at all? It makes a huge problem if the credit card payment goes through, the Account object is updated and then the Payment Object never gets created even though the cards get charged and account shows a new payment.

```
import gateway
import datetime
import smtplib
merchant = {'merchantKey': '',
            'processorId': '',
            }
data = dict(merchant)
cardNumber = request.GET.get("cardNumber", "")
cardExpYear = request.GET.get("cardExpYear", "")
cardExpMonth = request.GET.get("cardExpMonth", "")
fullName = request.GET.get("fullName", "")
accountIDOriginal = request.GET.get("accountID", "")
accountID = accountIDOriginal.split('-')[0]
if Payments.objects.filter(accountID=accountID,paymentDate=str(datetime.date.today())).count() > 0:
    return HttpResponse('You Have already ran a payment today.')
else:
    theAccount = Account.objects.get(acctno=accountID)
    collectorID = theAccount.collector_id
    collectorEmail = Collector.objects.get(pk=collectorID).email
    ownerZip = request.GET.get("ownerZip", "")
    ownerState = request.GET.get("ownerState", "")
    ownerStreet = request.GET.get("ownerStreet", "")
    ownerCity = request.GET.get("ownerCity", "")
    cVV = request.GET.get("cVV", "")
    transactionAmountString = request.GET.get("transactionAmount", "")
    transactionAmount = Decimal(transactionAmountString)
    if ownerState == "CO" or ownerState == "co" or ownerState == "Co":
        creditCardCharge = round(transactionAmount * Decimal(1.00),2)
    else:
        creditCardCharge = round(transactionAmount * Decimal(1.03),2)
    data['cardNumber'] = cardNumber
    data['cardExpMonth'] = cardExpMonth
    data['cardExpYear'] = cardExpYear
    data['ownerState'] = ownerState
    data['ownerCity'] = ownerCity
    data['ownerName'] = fullName
    data['ownerStreet'] = ownerStreet
    data['ownerState'] = ownerState
    data['ownerZip'] = ownerZip
    data['cVV'] = cVV
    data['transactionAmount'] = creditCardCharge
    sale = gateway.RestGateway(data)
    resultsCC = str(sale.createSale())
    if sale.status == 'Success':
        fromaddr = 'email@domain.com'
        subject = 'New CC Payment'
        actualaccountid = Account.objects.get(acctno=accountID).accountid
        email = str(fullName) + str(' has made a payment for the amount of ') + str(transactionAmount) + str(
        '. Account ID is ') + str(accountID) +  str("""
       https://web.domain.com/admin/web/account/""") + str(actualaccountid)
        message = 'Subject: %s\n\n%s' % (subject, email)
        username = 'emailaddress'
        password = 'password'
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(username, password)
        server.sendmail(fromaddr, collectorEmail, message)
        server.quit()
        previousBalance = theAccount.balance
        clientNumber = Account.objects.get(acctno=accountID).cl_no
        client = Client.objects.get(cl_no=clientNumber)
        clRates = Decimal(client.cl_rates)
        clientsRateCorrected = clRates / Decimal(100.00)
        agFee = Decimal(clientsRateCorrected) * transactionAmount
        # calculate taxes
        if client.cl_taxable == "Y":
            tax = transactionAmount * Decimal(client.cl_taxrate)
            tax = transactionAmount * Decimal(client.cl_taxrate)
        else:
            tax = '0.0'
        # calculate new balance
        newBalance = Decimal(theAccount.balance) - transactionAmount
        # save Account with new Balance
        theAccount.balance = Decimal(newBalance)
        # set new DLP
        theAccount.lastamt = transactionAmount
        theAccount.doctor_id = 3
        theAccount.lastpay = str(datetime.date.today())
        theAccount.save()
        newPayment = Payments(paymentDate=str(datetime.date.today()),
                          # claimDate='',
                          accountID_id=theAccount.acctno,
                          firstName=theAccount.first,
                          lastName=theAccount.last,
                          clientID=clientNumber,
                          pAgency=transactionAmount,
                          pClient=0.00,
                          rate=client.cl_rates,
                          agFee=agFee,
                          taxable=client.cl_taxable,
                          tax=tax,
                          # desc='',
                          fee=0.00,
                          # expense='',
                          # adjust='',
                          # salesman='',
                          balance=newBalance,
                          # intDue='',
                          status='$',
                          # area='',
                          ref_no='',
                          collector=theAccount.collector,
                          # cref_date='',
                          clName=client.cl_name,
                          # referred='',
                          # contact='',
                          isCC=True,
                          isProccessed=False,
                          creditCardChargedDate=str(datetime.date.today()),
                          )
        newPayment.save()
        paymentID = newPayment.paymentID
        handlingFee = Decimal(creditCardCharge) - Decimal(transactionAmount)
        clientName = Client.objects.get(cl_no=theAccount.cl_no).cl_name
        colelctorEmail = Collector.objects.get(name=theAccount.collector).email
        newReceipt = Invoice(paymentID=paymentID,
                         clientName=clientName,
                         accountNumber=theAccount.acctno,
                         claimNumber=theAccount.ref_no,
                         handlingFee=Decimal(handlingFee),
                         paymentAmount=Decimal(transactionAmount),
                         paymentAmountWithHandling=Decimal(creditCardCharge),
                         ccCharge=True,
                         newBalance=Decimal(newBalance),
                         previousBalance=Decimal(previousBalance),
                         originalBalance=Decimal(theAccount.referred),
                         paymentDate=str(datetime.date.today()),
                         collector=theAccount.collector,
                         fullName=fullName,
                         lastFourofCard=1234,
                         collectorEmailAddress = colelctorEmail
                         )
        newReceipt.save()
        return HttpResponse(str('https://domain.com/invoices/') + str(newReceipt.pk) + str('/') + str(theAccount.acctno) + str('/'))
   #return HttpResponse(final)
    else:
        fromaddr = 'email'
        subject = 'Error CC Payment'
        actualaccountid = Account.objects.get(acctno=accountID).accountid
        email = str(fullName) + str(' has attempted to make a payment for the amount of ') + str(transactionAmount) + str(
        '. Account ID is ') + str(accountID) + str("""

        Attached are the error results from the card being ran:
        """) +  str(resultsCC)
        message = 'Subject: %s\n\n%s' % (subject, email)
        username = 'email'
        password = 'Password'
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(username, password)
        server.sendmail(fromaddr, collectorEmail, message)
        server.quit()
        response = "An Error Has Occured. Please Contact ____ for Help."
        return HttpResponse(response)
```

Comment: "if the code has some indent problems, it's due to how I pasted it into Stack overflow" => we actually don't care - if your code is badly indented we can't tell what it's really doing, so it's __your__ duty to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone know what I can do to ensure that all the objects are saved or none at all?

Yes, it's called a transaction, and it's [fully documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/).

Comment: Even without transactions, is there a way to ensure that all save properly as you would think the intended behavior would be?